# Boost filesystem3 not found when building Gazebo from source

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am building Gazebo 1.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 and have all the dependencies needed for the build in place. I am using Boost library version 1.52. The build process has no problems through configuring using cmake, but during linking the gazebo executable file, I run into the message

`common/libgazebo_common.so.1.3.1: undefined reference to` boost::filesystem3::detail::status(boost::filesystem3::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'`,

along with other errors in finding Boost filesystem3 calls.

I have applied the [patch from here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/278/use-boost-filesystem-version-3) but it still does not fix the filesystem3 compatibility issue.

Has anyone compiled Gazebo using Boost library 1.52, and resolved the filesystem3 conflicts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/818/boost-filesystem3-not-found-when-building-gazebo-from-source/) by [yipenghuang0302](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/146/yipenghuang0302/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This problem was a result of having multiple installations of lib Boost.

---

Originally posted by [yipenghuang0302](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/146/yipenghuang0302/) with karma: 26 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1